# How to set the modifiedDate on a google drive file in iOS AND prevent duplicate file names

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-objc-client

I found the way in iOS (not obvious to me) to insert a file into a google drive folder using the standard queryForFilesInsertWithObject with uploadParameters and setting the folder id in a GTLDriveParentReference object, adding that object to an array, and assigning that array to the uploaded file's "parents" property.  What I haven't yet figured out is how to overwrite any existing google drive file with a newer version without creating a duplicate.  I would also like to stamp the new uploaded google drive file with the same date-time stamp as my local device file.  When I try to use the file/update method and set the file.modifiedDate and query.setModifiedDate=YES, I always get a 400 Bad Request.

I can use patch to change the title just fine, but I can't set the modifiedDate using the api. I was able to change the modifiedDate using Google's Try it! APIs Explorer, so Google's servers are working fine. Here is the code that fails:

```
GTLDriveFile *file = [GTLDriveFile object];
NSString *fId = insertedFile.identifier;
file.title = @"Tony.jpg";
file.modifiedDate = myNewGoogleDate; // "2012-12-31T08:00:00+00:00"

GTLQueryDrive *qu = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesPatchWithObject:file fileId:fId];
qu.setModifiedDate = YES;

[service executeQuery:qu completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,...
```

Take out the two lines with modifiedDate and the google-drive file title changes just fine.  I traced into the api call to executeQuery and found that the following results as "DataToPost".

```
{"method":"drive.files.patch","id":"gtl_7","jsonrpc":"2.0",
"params": {"setModifiedDate":true,"resource":
{"modifiedDate":"2012-12-31T08:00:00+00:00",
"title":"Tony.jpg"},"fileId":"0BxRlXPR_hfR9OEJSdDdyQjkyaE0"},"apiVersion":"v2"}
```

Does anyone see "Bad Request" in this post?  The error returned from the executeQuery is:

```
Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be
completed. (Bad Request)" UserInfo=0x80724b0 {error=Bad Request,
GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x806a7a0: {message:"Bad Request" code:400 data:[1]},
NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Bad Request)}
```

Does anyone have some code to set the modifiedDate that works?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `queryForFilesUpdateWithObject` instead to update the file using the original's `fileId` to ensure that the correct file is updated.

```
+ (id)queryForFilesUpdateWithObject:(GTLDriveFile *)object
                         fileId:(NSString *)fileId
               uploadParameters:(GTLUploadParameters *)uploadParametersOrNil {
```

Comment: That's what I was using.  I first upload the file using queryForFilesInsertWithObject which returns the new file id.  I then use:
 
insertedFile.modifiedDate = myDate;
GTLQueryDrive *qu = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesUpdateWithObject:insertedFile
               fileId:insertedFileId
               uploadParameters:nil]
qu.setModifieDate = YES;

and I get: Bad Request code:400.  Does JSON have anthing to do with the problem?

Comment: Typically patch is more appropriate than update; see  https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/Introduction#Partial_Updates

Comment: Thanks, @grobbins, but I still can't get it to work.  I expanded my question above.

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate file name is avoided if you supply the same pre-existing identifier (as probably explained in the answer above).  The modifiedDate can be set using the GTLDateTime construction.  Both solutions are shown below:

```
NSString *fileID = gF.identifier;
gF.modifiedDate  = [GTLDateTime dateTimeWithDate:myNSDate timeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

if (fileID==0) query  = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:gF               uploadParameters:upParams];
else           query  = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesUpdateWithObject:gF fileId:fileID uploadParameters:upParams];
query.setModifiedDate = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working with GoogleAPIClient v3 and i couldn't see any bad request.

```
driveFile = [GTLDriveFile object];
driveFile.modifiedTime  = [GTLDateTime dateTimeWithDate:[NSDate date] timeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

output:
(lldb) po driveFile.modifiedTime
GTLDateTime 0x157a06470: {2016-08-10T13:44:33.609+05:30}
```